# Is there a more efficient admin search function/plugin?

Tags: admin, search

Writers on our large Wordpress installation love to use the the content searching functionality.  As convenient as this functionality is, the complexity of its queries slows down our database considerably.  Here's an example of an SQL query I found in our slow query log from just a few minutes ago:

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID 
FROM wp_posts  
WHERE 1=1  
AND (
    ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Made%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Made%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%in%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%in%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%the%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%the%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%shade:%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%shade:%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%Easy%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%Easy%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%tips%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%tips%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%to%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%to%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%care%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%care%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%for%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%for%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%your%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%your%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%outdoor%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%outdoor%')) 
    AND ((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%furniture%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%furniture%'))
)  
AND wp_posts.post_type = 's5_post' 
AND (
    wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'future' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'draft' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending' 
    OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private'
)  
ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 20
```

Check out the size of that guy!  It's no wonder it runs slowly.

I'd be interested to hear ideas on how to code up some tweaks to this functionality to make it be a bit more efficient.  (I already have a few ideas of my own; hopefully yours are better than mine! :) )

Comment: The best way to improve search is to use a search application. MySQL wasn't built around search. There are several open source options: Elasticsearch, Sphinx, Solr. You'll find plugins for each of these. Each of these is basically a database built around search as opposed to relational data. The plugins will keep your search app synced with WordPress and then direct searches through the search app.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @SeamusLeahy! Do these search applications (and their related plugins) work for the admin area?  I'm mainly concerned with speeding up the admin area's search functionality.

Comment: @rinogo Please follow up on your questions. Some of them are quite good, but it seems like you abandoned them...

Answer (score 3):

### Altering the `WHERE` clause

There's a filter named `posts_search` that allows to filter the SQL `WHERE` clause used for the query during search (when `WP_Query::is_search()` returns true and `WP_Query->s` is set):

```
add_filter( 'posts_search', 'wpse134392PostsSearchSQL', 20, 2 );
function wpse134392PostsSearchSQL( $sql, $wp_query )
{
    // Alter SQL clause here

    return $where;
}
```

### Custom `ORDERBY`

To intercept the `ORDERBY` statement (for e.g. to sort by author, so the author who searches gets his posts first/last), you can make use of `posts_search_orderby`:

```
add_filter( 'posts_search_orderby', 'wpse134392PostsSearchOrderbySQL', 20, 2 );
function wpse134392PostsSearchOrderbySQL( $orderby, $wp_query )
{
    if ( is_admin() )
        return $GLOBALS['wpdb']->posts."post_date";

    return $orderby;
}
```

### Fine grained SQL

You can as well alter the `posts_clauses` or `pre_get_posts` to return even more fine tuned results by checking inside your callback if `is_admin()` and `$query->is_search()` are `TRUE`.

### Don't search *everything*

To exclude common terms that won't help, you can use `WP_Query::get_search_stopwords()` - or better: A callback on the filter. Currently the stopwords are:

```
about,an,are,as,at,be,by,com,for,from,how,in,is,it,of,on,or,that,the,this,to,was,what,when,where,who,will,with,www
```

An example filter callback:

```
add_action( 'wp_search_stopwords', 'wpse134392SearchStopwords' );
function wpse134392SearchStopwords( $stopwords )
{
    return $stopwords + array(
        'my',
        'your',
        'easy',
    );

}
```

Hint: It looks like something (a plugin probably) is already intercepting your callback as there're words in there that shouldn't get searched.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend changing your query to with your $args being something like this

```
    $args = array(
        'post_status' => array('pending', 'draft', 'future' ), 
        'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'movie', 'book' ),
        'orderby' => 'date', 
        'order' => 'DESC',
        's' => 'keyword'
    );
    $search_query = new WP_Query($args);
```

There is also I more detailed description [here](http://www.billerickson.net/code/wp_query-arguments/).  The only thing I can't seem to find is to query for multiple keywords.  Maybe if you do something like this it could work

```
's' => 'keyword1+keyword2+keyword3'
```